# ImportError: cannot import name 'moduleTNC' - python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm having a problem in python when I try to import linear_model from sklearn library: `from sklearn import linear_model`. I have just installed it via pip simply in this way: `pip install sklearn`. I know that to avoid this error suffices  uninstall and reinstall sklearn, but it didn't work. I also installed it via conda but opening the idle (is that correct?) it gives the same error.
How to avoid it?
NB: If I use jupyter from conda it works well as it should.

Comment: If you installed it from conda, then it can be only used within the conda environment. If you want to use it in other terminals or system environment, you need to install the library there again, or activate the conda environment in IDLE

Comment: how to activate it in idle?

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and resolved it with:

```
conda remove scipy scikit-learn -y
conda install scipy scikit-learn -y
```

I saw it [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4830#issuecomment-109897634), where many other people said it solved their problems too.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'moduleTNC'

It can be solved by renaming `moduletnc.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` with `moduleTNC.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` in:

```
AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\optimize
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't mark as possible duplicate, so I'm just pasting here. If that's a wrong behaviour, I'm sorry:

[Import module works in Jupyter notebook but not in IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490337/import-module-works-in-jupyter-notebook-but-not-in-idle)

The reason is that your **pip/conda** installed library paths are not accessible by python IDLE. You have to add those library paths to your environment variable(PATH). To do this open my computer > properties > advanced system settings > system.

Under **environment variables** look for **PATH** and at the end add the location of installed libraries. [Refer this](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation#python-install) for more details on how to add locations in path variable. Once you do these you will be able to import the libraries. In order to know what locations python searches for libraries you can use

```
import sys 
print sys.path
```

This will give you a list of locations where python searches for libraries. Once you edit the PATH variable those locations will be reflected here.

[Refer](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html) this also in order to know how to add python library path.

**Note:** The tutorial is a reference on how to edit PATH variable. I encourage you to find the location of installed libraries and follow the steps to edit the same.

Comment: So I added `C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages` (path that contains all the libraries) into env variable. Is it right? No, I have just tried...could you be more specific? I'm a newbie

Comment: That should be correct. Have you tested after adding the path?

Comment: Right now, how it is installed? Via conda?

Comment: Both pip and conda! I uninstalled it from pip and now the idle doesn't recognize anything named sklearn. I also add anaconda libraries to env variables

Comment: You have to add conda's site-packages as env variable. I don't now the exact directory, but is something like AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

Comment: I installed it for all users, so it should be C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the Anaconda3's site-packages.

Comment: No, it doesn't recognize the libraries installed via conda: ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'